# Update Rule on a Postgres 9.6 View

Tags: postgresql, view, sql-update, rules

I have a view that is sitting on top of table, it's simple select * from table view, no filters, no joins.

This rule is going to be used by app, instead of a base table. I am creating rule where any update to the view should redirect to the base table. All these complications because of partition and inheritance.

The question is 'Is it possible to update the table without listing all the columns in update syntax?'

Current Rule:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE update_table AS
    ON UPDATE TO schema.view
    DO INSTEAD
UPDATE schema.base_table
SET pk = new.pk, column1 = new.column1, column2 = new.column2, column3 = new.column3, ------------
WHERE base_table.pk = old.pk;
```

I want to avoid listing all the columns, because if there is a new column added to the base table, we will have to remember updating this rule.

Comment: "*All these complications because of partition and inheritance*" - then upgrade to Postgres 11 - it has **much** better support for partitioning and you don't need any triggers or rules to make sure a row is inserted into the correct partition.

Comment: We are planning to upgrade to 11, but currently we can't and meanwhile we have to partition a few large tables.

Comment: I found the solution though, it seems we don't need UPDATE rule on a view. Hence, there is no need to create the rule, but I would still be interested in knowing the answer if we can do it or not.

Comment: Rules are discouraged for this purpose. `INSTEAD OF` triggers are the recommended way to make a view updateable (or do some more elaborated stuff when updating it). Did you consider [pg_partman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman) to manage your partitions?

Comment: We did not considered it.